# How to shift elements from a column to another based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a df

| Date_time | Sam_house | Jack_House | Stella_House |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 1:00 | Sam | Jack | Stella |

Considering
(i) Sam moves from one house to another every 10 minutes
(ii) Jack moves from one house to another every 20  minutes
(iii) Stella Moves from one house to another every 30 minutes

Want to get the result_df on input of required time

example input 1 ------> 01.01.2023 1:10

result_df

| Date_time | Sam_house | Jack_House | Stella_House |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 1:10 |  | Sam Jack | Stella |

example input 2 ----> 01.01.2023 1:30

result_df

| Date_time | Sam_house | Jack_House | Stella_House |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2023 1:30 | Stella |  | Sam Jack |

Comment: At 1:30, Sam should be in his house with Stella, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your dataframe with few math operations:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initial data
origin = '2023-01-01 01:00:00'
freq = 10  # timestep, 10min
periods = 6  # periods, 6 * 10min
num_house = 3  # number of houses

window = np.arange(0, periods*freq+1, freq) # window, 1 hour

# 0+, 1+, 2+ <- initial positions
sam_pos = (0 + window // 10) % num_house
jack_pos = (1 + window // 20) % num_house
stella_pos = (2 + window // 30) % num_house

data = {
    'index': ['sam', 'jack', 'stella'],
    'columns': pd.Timestamp(origin) + pd.to_timedelta(w, unit='min'),
    'data': [sam_pos, jack_pos, stella_pos]
}

# Build the final dataframe
# Build the final dataframe
df = (pd.DataFrame(**data).T.rename_axis(index='Datetime', columns='House')
        .stack().rename('Position').reset_index()
        .pivot_table(index='Datetime', columns='Position', values='House',
                     aggfunc=' '.join, fill_value='')
        .add_prefix('House_'))
```

Output:

```
Position                 House_0      House_1          House_2
Datetime                                                      
2023-01-01 01:00:00          sam         jack           stella
2023-01-01 01:10:00                  sam jack           stella
2023-01-01 01:20:00                            sam jack stella
2023-01-01 01:30:00   sam stella                          jack
2023-01-01 01:40:00  jack stella          sam                 
2023-01-01 01:50:00  jack stella                           sam
2023-01-01 02:00:00          sam  jack stella
```